# Web browser is returning nothing - function error?

Tags: php, mysql, class

When I access this from a web browser it returns nothing other than echo'd text, I know this is similar to another question I posted but I can't make sense of it?

```
<?php
include('config.php');
include('database.php');

   class conversion{

public $amnt;
public $cc_from;
public $cc_to;

public function __construct (){
    $this->amnt = htmlspecialchars($_GET["amnt"]);
    $this->cc_from = htmlspecialchars($_GET["from"]);
    $this->cc_to = htmlspecialchars($_GET["to"]);
    }

function convert($this->amnt,$this->cc_from,$this-cc_to,$decimals=2){
$db_rate_from = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _currency WHERE country_code='$this-    >cc_from'") or die(mysql_error());;
$query_row_from = mysql_fetch_array($db_rate_from);
$rate_from = ($query_row_from['rate']);
echo $rate_from;
echo "</br>rate to</br>";

$db_rate_to = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _currency WHERE country_code='$this->cc_to'")     or die(mysql_error());;
$query_row_to = mysql_fetch_array($db_rate_to);
$rate_to = ($query_row_to['rate']);
echo $rate_to;
echo "</br>conversion</>";

$conversion = (number_format(($amnt/$rate_from)*$rate_to,$decimals));
echo $conversion;

} }
$var = new conversion();
$var->convert($amnt,$cc_from,$cc_to);
?>
```

Comment: Nice SQL injection holes. using htmlspecialchars to "safe" SQL data is like using a toilet paper square to clean up an ocean.

Comment: Indenting your code can help, just FYI later on.

Comment: What is your expected output and what is your actual output?

Comment: Btw, don't use $query_row_to[rate]. Use either $query_row_to['rate'] or $query_row_to[$rate].

Comment: Most likely the queries are invalid. Add `echo mysql_error()` after the queries. `$db_tbprefix` sounds like it might contain only a prefix, not a table name.

Comment: Marc B - this code is only being used locally, some test code.
Minitech - It is pretty and indented on my IDE but copying it lost all format.

Comment: Aron - It should return like this;
1.0005
rate from
1.0000
rate to
0.7842
conversion
0.7845921

Comment: No error checking. No debugging of your actual SQL queries. What do you wonder about?

Comment: in `$query_row_to[rate]` what is `rate`? Is it db-table field, or variable (that wasn't declared?

Comment: So, what does your test output/debugging give you? mysql_error(), mysql_num_rows(), print_r($query_row_from), print_r($_GET), print_r(array($rate_to, $amnt, $rate_from, $decimals));

Answer (score 3):

Given this:

```
$db_rate_from = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tbprefix WHERE country_code='$this->cc_from'");
```

where is `$db_tbprefix` defined? Nowhere, causing your query to be `SELECT * FROM WHERE ...`. If you had proper SQL error handling code, this would've been clear to you. At absolute bare minimum, you should have something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());
```

which would abort the script on a query failure and tell you exactly why the query failed.

As well, htmlspecialchars is NOT intended for database operations. It does absolutely nothing to prevent SQL injection. For that, you have to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: I have error mysql_error() in my config file so it should bring that up surely?

Comment: No. You have to check EVERY mysql_query(), mysql_connect(), etc... call you perform.

Comment: One solution to get this right all the time is not to use mysql_query directly, but use your own my_own_query (or whatever) that always does mysql_query('...') or my_error_handling_function();

Answer (score 2):

One thing I notice is that you call your method without parameters.

```
$var->convert();
```

Yet it is declared to take three mandatory parameters.

```
function convert($amnt,$cc_from,$cc_to,$decimals=2)
```

And btw, don't use $query_row_to[rate]. Use either $query_row_to['rate'] or $query_row_to[$rate].

Edit:

How about something like this? Use global $db_tbprefix and skip object orientation.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
include('database.php');

    function convert($amnt,$cc_from,$cc_to,$decimals=2) {
        global $db_tbprefix;
        $db_rate_from = mysql_query("SELECT rate FROM $db_tbprefix WHERE country_code='$cc_from'") or die mysql_error();
        $query_row_from = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_rate_from);
        $rate_from = $query_row_from['rate'];

        $db_rate_to = mysql_query("SELECT rate FROM $db_tbprefix WHERE country_code='$cc_to'")  or die mysql_error();
        $query_row_to = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_rate_to);
        $rate_to = $query_row_to['rate'];

        return number_format(($amnt/$rate_from)*$rate_to,$decimals);
    }


echo convert(floatval($_GET["amnt"]), mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["from"]), mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["to"]));
?>
```

Edit 2: only select what you need, in this case rate. And use mysql_fetch_assoc rather than than mysql_fetch_array which will double your memory consumption and slow down your code.

Comment: Thanks - I've put $var->convert($amnt,$cc_from,$cc_to); instead, but netbeans is saying they are uninitialized?

Comment: That's because they are. You have to initialize them globally or you need to change your method to skip the parameters and use $this->amnt, $this->cc_from, $this->cc_to instead.

Comment: Do I need to have them outside of the class aswell? They are there at the start of the class

Comment: A friendly tip: perhaps you should skip object orientating your php code until you are more proficient in php. Object Orientation in PHP is a bit more tricky than in other languages, and personally I think it is mostly abundance. For your specific code, it looks like real waste. Simply having a function like this function convert($amnt,$cc_from,$cc_to,$decimals=2){/*...*/} which is called like this "convert(floatval($_GET['amnt']), mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cc_from']), mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cc_to']));" would make more sense.

Comment: I agree entirely, but! I need it to be OO for later use where it gets a lot more indepth.

Comment: Please see my revised code and advise - I'm getting a 500 error from the server now

Comment: Ok, then you can probably skip the parameters (except $decimals=2) from your method and replace $amnt, $cc_from and $cc_to with $this->amnt, $this->cc_from and $this->cc_to. As well, make sure that $db_tbprefix is in your scope (it probably wasn't). do a "global $db_tbprefix" in your function and do an echo $db_tbprefix, just to make sure it is as expected.

Comment: Change your function convert($this->amnt,$this->cc_from,$this-cc_to,$decimals=2) to convert($decimals=2). And add "global $db_tbprefix;" as your first line in your method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8077/discussion-between-remi-bond-and-aron-cederholm)

Answer (score 1):

haven' tested it ... but the possibility i can find is you are passing parameters in function convert while defining it so you need to pass the same param while calling it... OR if the variables are the reference from the predefined one then use them like this

```
function convert($this->amnt,$this->cc_from,$this->cc_to,$decimals=2){
   }
```

Comment: I think `$this->` part shouldn't be in arguments list :)